# WITH clause causing ORA-32044

Tags: sql, oracle, recursive-query

I have a query which is used in an OBIEE report which erroring out for "ora-32044 while executing recursive WITH query". Tried running in SQL and it is erroring out in there as well. Can anyone take a look at the query and suggest how it can be run without the WITH clause. I have seen examples but without any level, for a case where WITH has been used in the middle of the query, how can it be rewritten without WITH clause so no ora-32044 occurs

```
   `SELECT 1 dummy, oh.order_number, ol.line_number, ol.shipment_number,
   oh.ordered_date, ot.NAME order_type, items.concatenated_segments item,
   items.description item_description
   ,bom.assembly_item 
   ,bom.component_item 
   ,bom.implementation_date 
   ,bom.disable_date as date_disabled 
   ,bom.component_item_description
   ,ol.flow_status_code line_status
   ,ol.ordered_quantity, 
    ol.shipped_quantity, 
    ol.unit_selling_price,
    ol.fulfilled_quantity, 
    ol.invoiced_quantity, 
    ol.cancelled_quantity,
    ol.schedule_ship_date, 
    ol.promise_date, 
    ol.actual_shipment_date,
    ol.request_date, 
    cust_acct.account_number customer_number,
    party.party_name customer, 
    ct.trx_number invoice_number,
    ctl.line_number inv_line_number, 
    ctl.extended_amount,
    ct.trx_date invoice_date, 
    ct.creation_date invoice_creation_date,
    wnd.NAME delivery_number, 
    wdd.released_status,
    hp2.party_name endcustomer,
    oh.attribute6 business_unit,
    TO_CHAR (ol.actual_shipment_date, 'MM/YY') shipped_month,
    TO_CHAR (ol.actual_shipment_date, '"Q"Q YY') shipped_qtr,
    TO_CHAR (ol.actual_shipment_date, 'YYYY') shipped_year,
    mc.segment1 product_group, mc.segment2 product_subgroup,
    items.attribute7 drive_capacity,
    items.attribute10 drive_form,
    items.attribute8 drive_speed,
    items.attribute6 drive_type,
    items.attribute12 AgileParttype,
    items.organization_id,
     case when dis.arithmetic_operator = 'NEWPRICE' then operand
     when dis.arithmetic_operator = '%' 
        then (ol.unit_selling_price* ol.ordered_quantity)*dis.operand/100.0
      else NVL((NVL (ol.pricing_quantity, 0) * NVL (dis.adjusted_amount, 0)),0) end 
         discount_amount
   FROM apps.oe_order_headers_all oh,
   apps.oe_order_lines_all ol,
   apps.wsh_new_deliveries wnd,
   apps.wsh_delivery_assignments wda,
   apps.wsh_delivery_details wdd,
   apps.ra_customer_trx_all ct,
   apps.ra_customer_trx_lines_all ctl,
   apps.oe_transaction_types_tl ot,
   (SELECT *
      FROM apps.mtl_system_items_vl
     WHERE organization_id = 84
     ) items,
   apps.hz_parties party,
   apps.hz_cust_accounts cust_acct,
   apps.hz_parties hp2,
   apps.hz_cust_accounts hca2,
   apps.mtl_item_categories mic,
   (SELECT *
      FROM apps.mtl_category_sets
     WHERE category_set_name = 'Inventory') ms,
   apps.mtl_categories mc,
     (select a.header_id, a.line_id ,a.list_header_id,a.creation_date,
   a.arithmetic_operator,a.unit_selling_price,a.operand,
   a.ordered_quantity, a.adjusted_amount
  from
  (select oh.header_id,     
  ol.line_id,pl.list_header_id,pl.creation_date,opa.arithmetic_operator, 
  ol.unit_selling_price,opa.operand,
  ol.ordered_quantity, opa.adjusted_amount
 from apps.oe_price_adjustments opa,
 apps.oe_order_lines_all ol,
 apps.oe_order_headers_all oh,
 apps.qp_list_headers_vl pl
 where oh.header_id = opa.header_id
 and ol.line_id = opa.line_id
 and opa.list_header_id = pl.list_header_id
 and opa.applied_flag = 'Y'
 AND opa.list_line_type_code = 'DIS') a,
 (select oh.header_id, ol.line_id,max(pl.creation_date) creation_date, min(operand)  
 operand
 from apps.oe_price_adjustments opa,
 apps.oe_order_lines_all ol,
 apps.oe_order_headers_all oh,
 apps.qp_list_headers_vl pl
 where oh.header_id = opa.header_id
 and ol.line_id = opa.line_id
 and opa.list_header_id = pl.list_header_id
 and opa.applied_flag = 'Y'
 AND opa.list_line_type_code = 'DIS'
 group by oh.header_id, ol.line_id) b
where 
a.header_id = b.header_id
and a.line_id = b.line_id
and a.creation_date = b.creation_date
and a.operand = b.operand ) dis 
,(
WITH recursiveBOM (parent_item_id,parent_item,parent_org_id,assembly_item_id,     
assembly_item,assembly_org_id,
component_item_id,component_item, component_item_description,implementation_date,   
disable_date)    AS
(
SELECT item.inventory_item_id parent_item_id
    ,item.segment1 parent_item
    ,item.organization_id parent_org_id
    ,bom.assembly_item_id
    ,msi.segment1 assembly_item
    ,bom.organization_id assembly_org_id
    ,bic.component_item_id
    ,msi2.segment1 component_item
    ,msi2.description component_item_description
    ,bic.implementation_date
    ,bic.disable_date
FROM apps.mtl_system_items_b item, apps.bom_bill_of_materials_v bom,   
apps.bom_inventory_components_v bic, apps.mtl_system_items msi, 
apps.mtl_system_items msi2
WHERE 1=1
AND bom.assembly_item_id   = item.inventory_item_id
AND bom.organization_id    = item.organization_id
AND bic.bill_sequence_id   = bom.common_bill_sequence_id
AND msi.inventory_item_id  = bom.assembly_item_id
AND msi.organization_id    = bom.organization_id
AND msi2.inventory_item_id = bic.component_item_id
AND msi2.organization_id   = msi.organization_id
AND bic.implementation_date IS NOT NULL
AND item.organization_id   = 84
AND item.inventory_item_id > 0
UNION ALL
 SELECT parent.parent_item_id
    ,parent.parent_item
    ,parent.parent_org_id
    ,bom.assembly_item_id
    ,msi.segment1 assembly_item
    ,bom.organization_id assembly_org_id
    ,bic.component_item_id
    ,msi2.segment1 component_item
    ,msi2.description component_item_description
    ,bic.implementation_date
    ,bic.disable_date
FROM recursiveBOM parent, apps.bom_bill_of_materials_v bom,    
apps.bom_inventory_components_v bic, apps.mtl_system_items msi, 
apps.mtl_system_items msi2
  WHERE 1=1
AND bic.bill_sequence_id   = bom.common_bill_sequence_id
AND msi.inventory_item_id  = bom.assembly_item_id
AND msi.organization_id    = bom.organization_id
AND msi2.inventory_item_id = bic.component_item_id
AND msi2.organization_id   = msi.organization_id
AND bic.implementation_date IS NOT NULL
AND bom.assembly_item_id   = parent.component_item_id
AND bom.organization_id    = parent.assembly_org_id
AND bom.organization_id    = 84
AND parent.assembly_org_id = 84
)
SELECT DISTINCT parent_item_id,parent_item,parent_org_id
    ,assembly_item_id
    ,assembly_item
    ,assembly_org_id
    ,component_item_id
    ,component_item
    ,component_item_description
    ,implementation_date
    ,disable_date  
FROM  recursiveBOM
) bom 
WHERE oh.header_id = ol.header_id
AND ol.line_id = wdd.source_line_id
AND wdd.source_code = 'OE'
AND wda.delivery_detail_id = wdd.delivery_detail_id
AND wda.delivery_id = wnd.delivery_id
AND ol.line_id = ctl.interface_line_attribute6(+)
AND ctl.customer_trx_id = ct.customer_trx_id(+)
AND oh.order_type_id = ot.transaction_type_id
AND ol.inventory_item_id = items.inventory_item_id
AND ol.sold_to_org_id = cust_acct.cust_account_id
AND cust_acct.party_id = party.party_id
AND oh.end_customer_id = hca2.cust_account_id(+)
AND hca2.party_id = hp2.party_id(+)
AND items.inventory_item_id = mic.inventory_item_id(+)
AND items.organization_id = mic.organization_id(+)
AND mic.category_id = mc.category_id(+)
AND mic.category_set_id = ms.category_set_id(+)
and ol.line_id = dis.line_id(+)
and ol.header_id = dis.header_id(+)      
AND bom.parent_item_id (+) = items.inventory_item_id 
AND bom.parent_org_id (+)  = items.organization_id `
```

Comment: It is almost always worth adding the exact error message relating to your question, after the end of your SQL statement.  Many times this will contain possibly vital information that you may have overlooked.

Comment: The error message for ORA-32044 is "cycle detected while executing recursive WITH query". Rewriting probably won't help, it may be your data that has a problem. You may have a bill of materials that contains components that are bills of materials that contain components that ... etc ... and at some point one of the child components contain its own grand-grand-parent, at which point the recursion would go into infinite loop (but it does not, it raises ORA-32044 instead.) Identify your "loop" in the data, then the code may perhaps run fine (unless the joins are the cause of infinite loop.)

Comment: I happen to have a spare EBS instance lying around and your code executed ran as APPS without issue.